# How to draw a rectangle on an image with mouse in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new to PyQt5. I need to draw a rectangle on an image. I found something that can draw on a mainwindow but I need to draw on an image with QLabel. QLabel is an widget. I am don't know how to draw rectangle on a widget.

```
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30,30,600,400)
        self.picture = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.picture.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 1111, 541))
        self.picture.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.picture.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(188, 188, 188);")
        self.picture.setText("")
        self.picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("G:/JOB files/JoBfiles/300/5.jpg"))
        self.image =QtGui.QPixmap("G:/JOB files/JoBfiles/300/5.jpg")
        self.picture.setScaledContents(True)
        self.picture.setObjectName("picture")
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        

        qp = QtGui.QPainter( self)
        br = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(100, 10, 10, 40))  
        #qp.drawPixmap(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end), self.picture)
        qp.setBrush(br)   
       # qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))       
        qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end) )       

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
ui=MyWidget()
mainwindow=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
mainwindow.addWidget(ui)
screen = app.primaryScreen()
size = screen.size()
mainwindow.setFixedWidth(size.width())
mainwindow.setFixedHeight(size.height())
mainwindow.showMaximized() 
mainwindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

this is what I got

[image]

Comment: NaQi, you messed up your image link again. Rolling back my edit to undo my changes messed up the image link and made it not clickable again. If you put it back how I had it the image will be clickable so people can zoom in on it to see better what it is.

Comment: thank you very much ... this is my very first question so sorry for that mistakes